# Cannot see in Object Browser a Referenced DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm, objectbrowser

I have an application to which I've added references to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk and Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow...but when I view Object Browser they don't appear anywhere in the Object Browser. They used to, but now they don't. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Right-click the reference and click "View in Object Browser".  What gets highlighted?

Comment: Whatever I had last selected in Object Browser. If I select Microsoft.VisualBasic and then use the reference to view in object browser - it shows Microsoft.VisualBasic, but if I have last viewed a different object, it shows that object (e.g. System.Runtime.Serialization).

Comment: This is happening for me as well, in an MVC4 project. It's notable that "System.Web.Mvc" is in the project as a NuGet package.

Comment: have your references moved directory?  has your current project moved directory?

Answer (score 0):

The dll is built against a later version of the .Net FW than your referencing project.  Upgrade the .Net FW version of your referencing project.